# Is there a way of showing there are arbitrarily big gaps between primes by contradiction?

Tags: prime-numbers

This may be a stupid question. So apologies in advance, if it is,

One proof of this is a straightforward construction.

For any $N$, consider $(N+1)!+2$, $(N+1)!+3$,..., $(N+1)!+N$. All of these numbers are composite.

My question is, is there a proof by contradiction which does not use this argument?

Comment: If the prime gaps were bounded, we would have $\pi(x) \geqslant c\cdot x$ for some $c > 0$. That contradicts the prime number theorem $\pi(x) \sim \frac{x}{\log x}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer  may I ask what $\pi(x)$  is called. this $x/\log(x)$ thing looks vaguely familiar.

Comment: $\pi(x)$ is the [prime counting function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_counting_function). That $\pi(x) \sim \frac{x}{\log x}$ is the celebrated prime number theorem.